# Manipulate Object Values in array and return the result in the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to perform `.toLocaleString()` on each of the arrays elements.
I am performing this for example to change `1111' to` 1,111`.
The data I am trying to access:

```
"Data": {
    "id": 1182,
    "time": 1637193600,
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "partner_symbol": "BTC",
    "zero_balance_addresses_all_time": 882855842,
    "unique_addresses_all_time": 920909797,
    "new_addresses": 476543,
    "active_addresses": 992178,
    "average_transaction_value": 18.723511893530098,
    "block_height": 710345,
    "hashrate": 163489266.17996278,
    "difficulty": 22674148233453.105,
    "block_time": 595.6643356643356,
    "block_size": 1267871,
    "current_supply": 18877162,
    "transaction_count": 293867,
    "transaction_count_all_time": 688002252,
    "large_transaction_count": 29400
  }
```

My code in attempt to manipulate the array:

```
getCryptoBlockchainData(selectedCrypto).then(cryptoTradingSignal => {
      if (cryptoTradingSignal.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
        cryptoTradingSignal.forEach(function (item, i) {
          this[i] = item.toLocaleString();
        }, cryptoTradingSignal);
        return this.setState({cryptoBlockchainData: cryptoTradingSignal});
      } else {
        return this.setState({cryptoBlockchainData: undefined});
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Array.prototype.map() will return a new array with the modified values. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't forEach over the properties of an object.  You can convert it to an array, do your thing, then convert it back to an object.

```js
getCryptoBlockchainData(selectedCrypto).then(cryptoTradingSignal => {
  if (cryptoTradingSignal.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
    const newSignal = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(cryptoTradingSignal).map(([k, v]) => ([k, v.toLocaleString()]))
    );
    return this.setState({cryptoBlockchainData: newSignal});
  } else {
    return this.setState({cryptoBlockchainData: undefined});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use `Array.prototype.map()` for that.

For your code maybe something like

```js
const newArray = Object.keys(object["Data"]).map(item => object[item].toLocaleString()));
```

See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: it seems to never go through the mapping - i set break points and it just hops over it

Comment: Can you please provide some more information and context in you language? Maybe I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the object keys using the Object.keys() function and change the values you want.

```js
 const dataObj = {
    "id": 1182,
    "time": 1637193600,
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "partner_symbol": "BTC",
    "zero_balance_addresses_all_time": 882855842,
    "unique_addresses_all_time": 920909797,
    "new_addresses": 476543,
    "active_addresses": 992178,
    "average_transaction_value": 18.723511893530098,
    "block_height": 710345,
    "hashrate": 163489266.17996278,
    "difficulty": 22674148233453.105,
    "block_time": 595.6643356643356,
    "block_size": 1267871,
    "current_supply": 18877162,
    "transaction_count": 293867,
    "transaction_count_all_time": 688002252,
    "large_transaction_count": 29400
  }
  
  Object.keys(dataObj).forEach(key => dataObj[key] = dataObj[key].toLocaleString());
  
  console.log(dataObj);
```

EDIT:

Incase your Object is nested as in your example, you also need to use the 'Data' key:

```
Object.keys(dataObj['Data']).forEach(key => dataObj['Data'][key] = dataObj['Data'][key].toLocaleString());
```